# How can I turn MapPos/(long,lat) into Pixels under Nutiteq?

Tags: gps, geometry, map-projections, nutiteq

I have deeply read the [`Nutiteq Api Reference`](http://nutiteq.github.io/hellomap3d/javadoc/index.html) and I haven't found built-in Methods to get the pixel representation of `longitude` and `latitude` on a device. There is nothing under the existing `Projections`, so I don't know how I could overcome this issue.

What I want to make is drawing a `circle` for my actual `GPS Location` like this,
[image]

NOT like `n-vertices Polygon` in `HelloMap3D`.

Getting Pixels of `lat`, `lon` and `radius` given `Zoom Level`under a given `Projection` is the Challenge because the rest would be calls like this

```
...
canvas.drawCircle(longitudeInPixel, latitudeInPixel, radiusInPixel, this.paintStroke); // <- For blue circunference
canvas.drawCircle(longitudeInPixel, latitudeInPixel, radiusInPixel, this.paintFill);   // <- For blue translucent circle
...
```

So, how could I turn `lat`, `lon` and `radius` into their pixel representation under `Nutiteq`?

I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapView has worldToScreen() method for this, see [Map Calculations](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Map-calculations) page in the Nutiteq Android demo project wiki.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jaak, that's just what I was seeking.